# Recursive XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have some XML that I am trying to deserialize      the xml below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <disproot  version="1.0">
   <header> 
     <msg-type> init_req </msg-type>
     <txn-id> 0090 </txn-id>
   </header>
   <body />
 </disproot>
```

My object is something like this.

```
[XmlRoot("disproot")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("header", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    Header header = new Header();
}


public class Header
{
    public Header()
    {

    }
    [XmlElement("txn-id")]
    public string TransactionId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("msg-type")]
    public string MessageType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My Header's object is not populated. The members are displaying as Null values. See below.
Request.Header.TasnsactionId's value is Null
Request.Header.MessageType's value is also Null

Anything wrong I am doing here?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Where does the closing "body" tag come from?

Comment: There is nothing “recursive” about this XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML serialization works only on public members. So, you can change the field to

```
public Header header = new Header();
```

and it should work fine. Although I would advise you against using public fields, you should probably make it into a property:

```
public Header Header { get; set; }
```